# Joomla Installation causes Internal Server Error

Tags: joomla, installation

I have a fresh install of Joomla 3.9.6 and trying a fresh install of CiviCRM 5.13.4 and I have been following the instructions found here https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/joomla/

I've tried this several times and every time I've got this error message

Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact the administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

I've contacted my host and after checking they came back with
"There are no console logs, no PHP errors, no apache errors. You're going to heave to reach out to them and ask for some insight as to where we can start looking, or what might be causing it with your max execution time set so high. "

I tried the max execution time set to 600 originally but then I tried setting it to 1000

Comment: How I fixed this was I installed it on a WAMP server then uploaded that to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You could post this as an answer to your own question. Perhaps add some more detail so that it can help others who may have the same problem.